# Best approach for creating API for web, android, iOS application

Tags: php, android, ios, laravel, api

I am working in a project which will have a web, android and iOS application.I have decided using laravel 5.4 to create the web application and also there will the rest api to feed all these app. The api should also be secured so that only my app can access them.

Anyone please tell me from your previous experience what will be the correct way and the best practice to do this

Comment: Use JWT or Session based tokens,it can secure your api calls

Comment: This question is too broad for SO. The answer to your question can be found in the Laravel docs. However, I will say Laravel is a good choice for this. Make use of Laravel Passport for authentication and use $request->wantsJson() within controller methods to create your API.

Comment: @Joe Niland thank you for the answer, i am planning to create api with laravel api route and also my web app will be on the same laravel project at the web route. Will this approach be nice? what do you suggest

Answer (score 0):

You can use Node.js or Python on which you can develop rest API very easily.The framework like [express](http://expressjs.com/) in Node.js and [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/) in python will let you get started with your API within 30 min.After that, you can deploy the API to [Heroku](https://www.heroku.com/) to get secure access

Answer (score 0):

If the web, android and IOS application relate to the same project / resources (e.g. database tables, etc.), the easiest way to do this would be a single Laravel project.

In your routes directory, you can [have 3 different files](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/routing#basic-routing) (say web.php, ios.php and android.php) to define the routes. Similarly, you can place controllers in separate directories while keeping the Eloquent models/migrations, etc. the same for all three.

To use different authentication methods for all three, you can [add custom guards](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/authentication#adding-custom-guards) in Laravel.

Comment: thank you for your answer. Is it really necessary for creating three separate files in route directory or all the api request from the web, android and ios can be handled in the api.php route

Answer (score 0):

I would not build anything in larvel and run away form php as soon as possible. Go learn node.js or django. Death to php.

The best current framework to builds apis is Sanic.

Sanic 33,342 Requests/sec 2.96ms Avg Latency

https://github.com/channelcat/sanic

I  also like python flask because it is very simple to understand and get something up and running quickly.

Your app currently does not need to be super optimal all you need to is getting working, But best practice wise i think the most important thing for building apis for mobile apps is backwards compatibility.

Sometimes your going to want to update the your app.
Users often don't update the apps. So if you build a new api all the people who dont update their app will get error messages. So just make sure you make a new route with the version name in the prefix in the app. There is alot of other things you can do like rate limiting,Salting your apis and ect. If you dont have that many users don't worry about this yet. Just build it and then latter learn when you need to learn in.